# Plotting a graph over a QPixmap using QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, alphablending, qpainter, qpixmap

I need to plot a real time graph keeping the background an image. Let's say I am plotting the graph with a red color.

But the logic I use for plotting is drawing small lines using painter.drawline, where painter is a pixmap painter. Then I am constantly drawing this pixmap using a painter to parent widget on a timer timeout() event. So it appears the updated Image (which is the graph) gets plotted in the Gui.

The pixmap is black in background and plotting pen color is red, So when it reaches the end of screen width, I have to start drawing the graph from position 0, but from the second cycle onwards I have to fill the previously drawn pixels (not the entire pixmap, just a rect of width few pixels and height, height of pixmap) with black color.

But now I need to keep a background image, and draw a graph over it. So the fillling with black color doesn't do, as I have to keep a background an image. So how can I plot a graph over an image like aforementioned?

Is there any way to blend two images such that the pixels only having a particular color (red) in source image is blended/replaced with corresponding pixels in destination image?

Answer (score 0):

Keep previously drawed Ys in memory than fill exactly the same pixels by corresponding background. It's faster and much more reliable.